# How to convert txt file into csv file？

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My .txt file looks like a matrix.It has 82 columns, about 1600 rows,the first column is gene,the first row is sample,the rest is the expression abundance of each gene in each sample.How to convert the txt file into a csv file using Python3?My data:[image]

Comment: How are the columns separated? Spaces? Tabs?

Comment: Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), you must provide enough details to reproduce your issue. Without a example of the input format and the matching expected output, any answer would be a wild guess.

Comment: I am sorry about that,it seems that I forgot to post the picture of my data,I posted it just now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow the Stackoverflow guidelines to ask your question.

I think as long as your columns in the TXT file are separated by a unique character that is not in the data of columns, you can use it as `sep` in `pd.read_csv(..., sep='<character>')`. Most common separators are `'\t', ' ', ',' , ';'`.

Comment: Thanks for your advice,I posted a picture of my data just now,You could have a look first

Comment: I would advise you to write python code to convert it into a format where your columns are in the first row separated by space and same goes for other rows

Comment: Thanks for your advice ,I got that

Comment: If my answer helped please give upvote